# Outlook item causes AftwerWrite event not available

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook Add-in. My goal is to get the EntryId assigned to an Outlook item just saved, in particular a Task item. So, in the appropiate wrapper class, I have:

```
public TaskItemEventWrapper(Outlook.TaskItem item)
        {
            Item = item;
            Id = new Guid();
            Item.BeforeRead += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_BeforeReadEventHandler(Item_BeforeRead);
            Item.Read += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReadEventHandler(Item_Read);
            Item.Unload += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_UnloadEventHandler(Item_Unload);
            Item.AfterWrite += Item_AfterWrite;
            Item.AttachmentAdd += Item_AttachmentAdd;
            Item.AttachmentRead += Item_AttachmentRead;
            Item.AttachmentRemove += Item_AttachmentRemove;
            Item.BeforeAttachmentAdd += Item_BeforeAttachmentAdd;
            Item.BeforeAttachmentPreview += Item_BeforeAttachmentPreview;
            Item.BeforeAttachmentRead += Item_BeforeAttachmentRead;
            Item.BeforeAttachmentSave += Item_BeforeAttachmentSave;
            Item.BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile += Item_BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile;
            Item.BeforeAutoSave += Item_BeforeAutoSave;
            Item.BeforeCheckNames += Item_BeforeCheckNames;
            Item.BeforeDelete += Item_BeforeDelete;
            Item.CustomAction += Item_CustomAction;
            Item.CustomPropertyChange += Item_CustomPropertyChange;
            Item.Open += Item_Open;
            Item.PropertyChange += Item_PropertyChange;
            Item.ReadComplete += Item_ReadComplete;
            Item.Write += Item_Write;
        }
void Item_AfterWrite()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Id --> " + Item.EntryID); 
}
void Item_Write(ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (!Cancel)
    {                
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Id --> " + Item.EntryID);
    }
}
```

If I try to inspect the EntryId in Write event, I get the null value.
If I try to inspect the EntryId in After_Write event, I get an error:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJm3V.png): [Error interop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJm3V.png)

So, my question is: when and where is the right place to get the new EntryId assigned to an item?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact error? Not everybody can read Spanish.

Comment: Sorry Dmitry. It says "element properties and methods cannot be used in this event procedure." If I can be notified with the EntryId assigned in After_Write event, when can I read it?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem as well.

Comment: In fact, not only the EntryId is not accessible but all the rest of properties too, at the AftwerWrite event. What a hell to read properties for a new item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access `Class` and `MessageClass` properties in that event. Your best bet is to enable a timer in the event handler (use the Timer class from the Forms namespace as it uses the main thread). When the timer fires, you will be out of the event handler and able to access any `MailItem` properties.

Comment: According to the PM, the fix will be in build 13513.10000 or later. That build should be in Insiders/Beta the next week or so and CC in late December or January